Adjusting figure to center plots along bottom row
I'm generating a figure with a variable number of plots. At the moment, if I use a number of plots that is not a multiple of three, the final plot(s) is left-aligned:

Here's my plotting function:
def mag_dist(dataset, magnames):
    num_magnames = len(magnames)
    num_cols = 3 if num_magnames > 3 else num_magnames
    num_rows = (num_magnames + num_cols - 1) // num_cols

    color = iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, num_magnames)))

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols, figsize=(12, 4*num_rows), sharex=True, sharey=True)
    axs = np.array(axs).reshape(num_rows, num_cols)

    for i, band in enumerate(magnames):
        bins = 50
        alpha = 1
        density = True

        row = i // num_cols
        col = i % num_cols
        ax = axs[row, col]

        counts, bins, _ = ax.hist(dataset[band], bins=bins, alpha=alpha, density=density, color=next(color), linewidth=3)

        ax.grid(True)
        ax.set_xlabel('')
        ax.set_yscale('log')

        max_x = np.max(dataset[band])
        ax.text(0.95, 0.95, f'Max: {max_x:.2f}', ha='right', va='top', transform=ax.transAxes, color='black', fontsize=15)

    # Remove empty subplots
    for j in range(i + 1, num_rows * num_cols):
        fig.delaxes(axs.flatten()[j])

    # Adjust layout for single and double plots (Copilot helped me with this bit)
    if num_magnames == 1:
        ax = axs.flatten()[0]
        ax.set_position([0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4])  # Center the single plot
    elif num_magnames == 2:
        ax1, ax2 = axs.flatten()[:2]
        ax1.set_position([0.1, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4])  # Space the first plot
        ax2.set_position([0.55, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4])  # Space the second plot

    plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
    plt.show()

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

if there is only one plot left after deleting the unused ones, center it in the figure, and
if there are two plots, space them out evenly along the bottom row.

Is there any way to do this?

maybe use different col in ax = axs[row, col] to use different place in grid. For your image should work axs[row, col+1]

or maybe you should first create subplots(num_rows, 1) for rows with single column - and later in every row use another subplots(1, 3) to create 3 columns in every row, and in last row use subplots(1, 1) to use full row for one plot. and this could allow to use subplots(1, 2) to create last row with 2 columns which would use full row.
